# Lost my account and need help to retrieve it

Tags: support, status-completed

I am Ihor Sypko, and once accessed stack exchange via 
Ihor.Sypko@dot.nj.gov which is no longer active since my 2016 retirement. I'm in need of help to get back to it.

Answer (score 11):

[Is this you?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14415/ihor-sypko?tab=profile) It's the only account with the username "Ihor Sypko" on our site. (Email addresses are private: moderators like myself can access them, but we can't share any details in a public space such as meta.)

Unfortunately, moderators can't help you with regaining access to a lost account, or with merging two user accounts together. Please [contact Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) explaining the details of your case - they're the only ones who can fix this.

Answer (score 10):

Your account would appear to be this one: [Ihor Sypko](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/14415/ihor-sypko). As it appears you no longer have access to the email of the main account you should follow the guidelines on [merging your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and stress to the team when they reach out to you that you no longer have access to the email of your main account.

For future reference it is important to not use a work email as unforeseen things can happen and you will then no longer have access. This goes for everyone.